# Firebase disk persistence not working after app restart

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have problem with firebase and disk persistence. When I go offline and use `setValue`:

```
 mDatabase.child(spamuId).setValue(contactSpam);
```

My database is updated when I go online without restarting my app but when I close the app and activate internet and open the app the database is not updated. Normally `keepSync()` isn't needed plus it copies all databaseReference to local storage if I understood well. I don't know what I'm doing wrong I put this in my application class :

```
 public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

So if someone can give me explanations I'll be grateful thanks.

edit : logcat

when i don't restart app and it's ok :

> 0-556/practical_solutions.fr.numfilterpro D/Persistence: Persisted a total of 1 rows and deleted 1 rows for a set at /ContactReportNoSpamFr/-LDGJofYHq5hTpwD8LqV/date in 1ms

when i restart :
i see no persistence message nothing.

**EDIT :** Log with simple count test button in my app :

> D/Persistence: Transaction completed. Elapsed: 20ms
>
> D/RepoOperation: Aborting transactions for path: /test. Affected:
>   /test
>
> D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Trying to fetch auth token
>
> W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod()
>   returned Gms: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdze@d0effca
>
> D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Error fetching token: A network error
>   (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has
>   occurred.
>                           pc_0 - Scheduling connection attempt
>
> D/ConnectionRetryHelper: Scheduling retry in 480ms
>
> D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Trying to fetch auth token
>   W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod()
>   returned Gms: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdze@d0effca
>
> D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Error fetching token: A network error
>   (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has
>   occurred.
>                           pc_0 - Scheduling connection attempt
>
> D/ConnectionRetryHelper: Scheduling retry in 1138ms
>
> D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Trying to fetch auth token
>
> W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod()
>   returned Gms: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdze@d0effca
>
> D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Error fetching token: A network error
>   (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has
>   occurred.
>                           pc_0 - Scheduling connection attempt
>
> D/ConnectionRetryHelper: Scheduling retry in 1404ms

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand the problem. Are you saying that the `contactSpam` value never gets sent to the server once you restore your internet connection?

Comment: If that is the case, the first thing to do is [add a completion listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#add_a_completion_callback) to see if the write is rejected by the server. If that doesn't show anything, [enable debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#setLogLevel(com.google.firebase.database.Logger.Level)) and check the logcat output to see what happens between the Firebase client and server when you restore the connection.

Comment: contactSpam never gets sent to server once the internet connection is restored only if i close the app before restoring connection. i'll check that all. Thanks.

Comment: it's relly going on my nerves. Nothing special i have this error : _06-01 11:15:06.259 1775-4141/? E/RemoteViewsAdapterServiceConnection: onServiceDisconnected_ and when i reconnect this but nothing is happening _06-01 11:14:14.912 4121-4142/practical_solutions.fr.bloqueurappelsetsms V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4_

Comment: Did you add a completion listener? If so, please update your question with the new code, and whether any of the callbacks fire? Also please add the log output to your question, particularly what happens after the connection is restored. You should see messages about the database client trying to reconnect to the server, and then sending those queued up writes.

Comment: onFailureListener when no connection prints websocket error and i edited the question. No persistence when i restart app.

Comment: That looks seems really limited. Is there any more about the Firebase client connecting to the server? If not, it might not be kicking off the connection. Maybe check if adding a `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()` may create the connection?

Comment: i send a message to firebase team i'll keep you informed.Thanks.

Comment: i edited my post whith more clarifications i put a test button on my app and had more infos in my log about persistence.

Comment: "A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred." That means the client can't reach the server. It's impossible to say from the logging why that is.

Answer (score 0):

Do you add this line in your manifest

```
android:name=".MyApplication"
```

If not add that and uninstall the app and install again

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
```

Comment: yes i added this line and put a log to see if it enters in my class.

Comment: You are working on a real device or virtual device. Some firebase function will not work in virtual devices.. That may not be the issue.. i just saying

Comment: real device but it's supposed to work like i did no ?

Comment: It is supposed to work..  please add push(). Before setValue and make sure everything works perfectly in active network condition    .. and then check your issue

Comment: i didn't put all my code i did push before and it's working with active network. The insert is done in Dialog launched from Activity itself launched in BroadcastReceiver with flags FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK and FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP. But it's inserted when i don't close the app. So i don't understand. Is the setValue() request supposed to be executed when i restart the app or when i enable connection ?